# conversion from urdf to dae fails while attempting to install ikfast for ur5

Tags: collada-urdf, collada, ros-industrial, ikfast, dae

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following this tutorial: http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Kinematics/IKFast while attempting to setup the ikfast solver for a ur5. I have gotten to the point where I am required to make a collada .dae file from the urdf file provided by the universal_robot repository. I have attempted to use collada_urdf to convert the file with the command:

```
rosrun collada_urdf urdf_to_collada ur5_robot.urdf ur5_robot.dae
```

however, this fails and gives the following terminal output:

```
[ WARN] [1402506614.940955494]: failed to load resource /home/robotcontroller/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/Base.dae
[ WARN] [1402506614.941741160]: failed to load resource /home/robotcontroller/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/Shoulder.dae
[ WARN] [1402506614.942159294]: failed to load resource /home/robotcontroller/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/UpperArm.dae
[ WARN] [1402506614.942558970]: failed to load resource /home/robotcontroller/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/Forearm.dae
[ WARN] [1402506614.943012926]: failed to load resource /home/robotcontroller/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/Wrist1.dae
[ WARN] [1402506614.943426780]: failed to load resource /home/robotcontroller/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/Wrist2.dae
[ WARN] [1402506614.943796708]: failed to load resource /home/robotcontroller/catkin_ws/src/universal_robot/ur_description/meshes/ur5/visual/Wrist3.dae
I/O error : No such file or directory
I/O error : No such file or directory
error : xmlNewTextWriterFilename : cannot open uri

Document successfully written to ur5_robot.dae
```

despite the "document successfully written" message, I can not find any output file named ur5_robot.dae. Is there another way to convert these files? Or another way to install IKFast to use with a ur5?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173432/conversion-from-urdf-to-dae-fails-while-attempting-to-install-ikfast-for-ur5/) by [airplanesrule](https://answers.ros.org/users/18786/airplanesrule/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-11**:
It is considered more 'future-proof' to include as much as possible any error text / output directly in your question, as links to services like pastebin can go stale. That would leave future readers guessing as to what the error actually was. I've edited your question to include it.

**Comment by [Stephane Caron](https://answers.ros.org/users/21907/stephane-caron/) on 2015-03-19**:
Same problem here on a fresh install of ROS Indigo, Ubuntu 14.04.2...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-19**:
I've seen more people report problems with trying to convert from urdt to dae on Indigo. See [robot_model/issues/89](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/89) fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this has been fixed by newer version of collada library, see  https://github.com/ros/robot_model/issues/118#issuecomment-164554380

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2015-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen `urdf_to_collada` fail if it was invoked without the package that contains the resources the urdf refers to on the package path. Can you make sure ROS can find the `ur_description` package? Something like:

```
rospack find ur_description
```

should return the correct directory.

Without more information: it should not matter, but I found it easiest to invoke `urdf_to_collada` in the directory containing the urdf (ie: `/urdf` in `ur_description`).

The `.dae` should then appear in the `cwd`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [airplanesrule](https://answers.ros.org/users/18786/airplanesrule/) on 2014-06-16**:
I just tried this and adding ur_description to the path gets rid of the [WARN] failed to load messages, but the 
I/O error : No such file or directory
I/O error : No such file or directory
error : xmlNewTextWriterFilename : cannot open uri 

still shows up

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-17**:
Very strange. I've just tried the conversion on my local system, and it works without any problems. Could you describe your environment a bit more? ROS version, workspace layout, etc (append to original question please).